# How to disable iframe from being highlighted

Tags: css, iframe

When I double click the white background, the iframe becomes highlighted, how do I disable that via css?

https://jsfiddle.net/516y29ka/

To reproduce, double mouse click the white background and you will see the iframe become highlighted.

How is that disabled via css?

```
<iframe width="642" height="361" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image]

Comment: `iframe {user-select: none;}` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `user-select: none;` on the iframe.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <style>
    .video-frame {
      user-select: none;
    }
  </style>

  <body>

    <iframe class="video-frame" width="642" height="361" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  </body>

  </html>
```

It's supported by almost all browsers: https://caniuse.com/?search=user-select

For more info refer spcifications: https://www.w3.org/TR/2021/WD-css-ui-4-20210316/#propdef-user-select

Comment: Why not this instead? iframe::selection {
  background: none;
}

Comment: good question! with the approach you've mentioned you are still allowing user to select the element, it's just that you are hiding the selection hint. And user can still do `ctrl+c` on the elment. And if you look in to clipboard there will be an object. On windows `window+v` will show you contents of clipboard. On the other hand `user-select: none;` completely disables selection process, and user can't do copy. If you try these approaches on text elements you'll notice the difference quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `user-select` and set it to `none`
To avoid compatibility issues, add vendor prefixes:
`-webkit-` `-ms-` `-moz-` `-o-`

```css
    .video-frame {
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
    }
```

Comment: -os-user-select: none; What’s that for? Did you just make it up?

Comment: *`-o-` for opera